# What is (Boolean. false) in the expression (if (Boolean. false) "logical true" "logical false")?

Tags: clojure

I'm new to Clojure so please excuse my ignorance but I am wondering what exactly the expression `(Boolean. false)` is?  I mean Boolean. is sitting there in the position of a function name.  What is the Boolean. function?

```
; CIDER 0.8.2 (Java 1.8.0_20, Clojure 1.6.0, nREPL 0.2.6)
user> ; What is the (Boolean. false) expression?
user> ; And what makes it logical "true"?
user> (if (Boolean. false) "logical true" "logical false")
"logical true"
user> (if false "logical true" "logical false")
"logical false"
```

Comment: Documentation is very explicit that you should only ever use the constant `Boolean/FALSE`.

Comment: If some library abuses java and returns a "different true" you can check for this with: `(if (true? (Boolean. false)) true false) => false`

Comment: I'm not really asking why it results in logical true.  I kind-of deduced that that there is some Clojure "truthiness" going on there; only nil and false are false.  What I'm asking is what "Boolean." IS in that expression.  Its sitting in the place of a function name, but its not a function (or at least (doc Boolean) doesn't think so.

Comment: It's a [Java constructor call](http://clojure.org/Java%20Interop-The%20Dot%20special%20form-(Classname.%20args*)).